# MySQL: Query two tables simultaneously

Tags: mysql, database

I work on a little social network, and want to implement a version of a friend feed, which shows updates from friends you follow, sorted by time.

Let's say there are two tables:

***connections*** - which stores users I follow by `myId` and `whoIFollowID` fields

and

***statusUpdates*** - which stores updates in `userID`, `status`, `time` fields.

How do I query the two tables simultaneously so that I get the status updates from ***statusUpdates*** table, and return only those WHERE `userID` matches with `whoIFollowID` from ***connections*** table, so that I can print them sorted by `time`?

Comment: It should perhaps be a Google search than a SO question - "Mysql query two tables simultaneously" :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
SELECT s.status from connections c
JOIN statusUpdates s
on s.userID = c.whoIFollowID
ORDER BY s.time
```

this uses [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) to select multiple tables

As suggested in the comments - you could add a `WHERE` condition to just select the statuses of the logged in user - this would be (for example) `WHERE c.myId = <the logged in user's userid>`

[For a very good explanation of joins read this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: You'll probably want to add a condition on c.myId being the current user to get updates for one user at a time.

Comment: Well, I just meant that your query will select all status updates of all users in the entire database that have a follower, not just the ones the logged in user is following. You may want to add a `where c.myId = <the logged in user's userid>`

Comment: ..am I too evil if I say that this week is the 3rd time i see a question of somebody who doesn't know how to join two tables and wants develop a social network??